# Reconstruct a vector from outer product with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, outer-product

Suppose I am given the matrix $A = xx^\top$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is some vector that is unknown.
How can I reconstruct the vector $x$ from $A$?

Answer (score 3):

With physicists' notation (and assuming that there is a scalar product, which helps identity the vector space with its dual), one has
$$ A = | \mathbf{x} \rangle \langle \mathbf{x} |$$

Up to the factor $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^2$, it's the projection on $\mathbb{R}\, \mathbf{x}$.

The factor $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^2$ coincides with the norm of the operator $A$, so one can recover $\pm \mathbf{x}$ by just picking a unit vector in the image $\mathrm{Im}(A)$, and multiply it by $\sqrt{\lVert A\rVert}$.

*Remark: I would rather call the "product" the tensor product of a vector with a linear form*

Comment: Note, though, that you can't actually recover $\mathbf{x}$, just the pair $\{\pm\mathbf{x}\}$: the operator $A$ encodes the unoriented subspace $\mathbb{R}\mathbf{x}$ and the length $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert$, no more and no less.